can DHCP server Detect type of windows?
I have a DHCP server and several clients, some running Windows 10 and some Windows 7. I want the DHCP server to be able to identify the Windows version of the clients using the vendor class and assign the settings I've specified accordingly. Also, I don't want to configure anything on the clients; I want the DHCP server to be able to detect the Windows version by itself. Is there a way to do this?

This question has already been answered here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/can-dhcp-server-determine-clients-os
The short answer is no, though there are some software packages that 'fingerprint' devices on the network to help provide options that might be helpful.
